ngIf error cause by the Breadcrump component
In Angular 8 app i`m using Breadcrump component comming from:
https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs

It works, but the problem is that it throws error in the console:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Theres html:
<breadcrumb #parent>  
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <ng-template ngFor let-route [ngForOf]="parent.breadcrumbs">
      <li *ngIf="!route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="" [routerLink]="[route.url]">{{ route.displayName }}</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{ route.displayName }}</li>
    </ng-template>
  </ol>
</breadcrumb>  

and those tags are causing the problem:
<breadcrumb #parent>  </breadcrumb>  

Is there any possibility that i can inject:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

into one of this files and make it work
https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs/tree/master/src
so there`s no error?
I tried importing it in .ts files but it didnt work.

The problem is in the component that uses the breadcrumb library from your application.
Make sure you have CommonModule added to the imports array of the module.
By module, I mean the module that has this component added to the declarations array of the module.

Hi, thanks for your answer! The problem is that in breadcrump.component.ts i import bith CommonModule and Browser Module, and they are both in the imports, but still theres error

@user28273827332 You should import Breadcrumb module not the component, since the module already has the imports

thanks for answer, but I did put Breadcrumb module inside the imports, but stil didint work...

@user28273827332 hope you removed the import for Breadcrumb component from your application, if possible share a stackblitz where the issue happens, for debugging!

@user28273827332 Could you share the component ts and HTML that uses this breadcrumb feature, also the module if this component is not standalone
